# how to drag UIScrollView to the very right depending on its childs

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is a very simple question,
I have a UIScrollView where I am setting childView horizontally from left to right. each time I am adding a new view, I want my ScrollView to scroll to the right so that the newly added view is seen on the screen.

Comment: What happens when you call your scroll view's `- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect
                   animated:(BOOL)animated` with the frame of your new view as the rect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new view you need to first increase the scroll view's content size.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: childV1.frame.width + childV2.frame.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)
```

Then you should be able to call `scrollRectToVisible` and pass in the most recently added child view's frame.

Comment: Thanks! can't I say childView10.frame.origin.x instead of adding?

Comment: Yeah should be able to. Depending on which direction you are inserting the new child views you may need to do `childView10.frame.origin.x + childView10.frame.width` to get the correct value.